# PDO Query Won't Work

Tags: php, pdo

I can't for the life of my figure out why this is not working. I have a different area of the website which uses almost exactly the same code as this and it works just fine. I'm sure it's something obvious, but I'm pretty new to this stuff. There is no error or anything; it just does nothing. The $name variable works fine (I've tested it), and the database is up to date.

```
try {
     $db = new PDO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
     $statement = $db->prepare("select first, last from users where email = $name");
     $result = $statement->fetch();
     $first = $result[first];
     $last = $result[last];
}catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if the answer to this is not "you didn't quote `$name`" when using it in the query. You should also be using the prepared statement as a parametrised query if you're going to go to all the trouble of using PDO and calling `prepare()`.

Comment: Uhmm i think you have a mistake here also `where email = name`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use execute()

```
try {
$db = new PDO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$statement = $db->prepare("select first, last from users where email = ?");
$statement->execute(array($name));
$result = $statement->fetch();
$first = $result[first];
$last = $result[last];}

catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: This worked, though you forgot the semicolon at the end of $statement. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch rows before you actually execute the query; you have only prepared the query.  The ultimate problem is that you lack a call to `$statement->execute()`.  The proper PDO idiom is something like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("select first, last from users where email = ?");
if (!$statement->execute(array($name))) {
    // Handle error
}
$result = $statement->fetch();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

Don't forget the `closeCursor()` call when you are finished fetching rows.  On some database systems that don't support concurrent queries by the same client, not calling this function may cause the next query to fail to execute.